# How to send SMS using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, sms

I have two devices on Android. First doesn't have GSM module, second have it. I need to **make calls and send SMS** from first device **programmatically**. 
For that I want to pair this devices with **Bluetooth**. As I know Android has built-in support for calls via BT. But how to send SMS from first device through second device using BT?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Its working fine for me](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Bluetooth/Download_Free_code_Bluetooth_Chat.htm) Bluetooth chating working using UUID.

Comment: As I understand this is chat between two devices via Bluetooth. But I need to send SMS from device without GSM module using Bluetooth and device with GSM module.